# adding zero to specific location of file names

Tags: command-line, bash, perl, batch-rename

I have a directory consists of several files. Files name are as follows;

```
0102920.05o
0203920.05o
0304920.05o
....
```

I need to add "0" for all files after the first 4 numbers like;

```
01020920.05o
02030920.05o
03040920.05o
```

Is there a way to do it with bash or perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this command

```
rename -n -v 's/(.{4})(.*)/${1}0${2}/' *
```

See if the result is what you want, remove `-n` and `-v` options.

### Explanation:

take this simple command:

```
rename 's/pattern/result/' filename(s)
```

Pattern can be regex. So, we can take different part of the text (which is the filename). If you don't understand it, google for regex.

So in the command I suggest, in pattern, it divide the filename into two parts: first part which is first four characters and the second part is the rest.

Now in the result part, we paste first part, add one 0 and then add the second part. As simple as this.

If you can make proper regex, you can easily do bulk rename.

Comment: Or also simply `rename -n -v 's/.{4}/${&}0/' *`

Comment: Most welcome. I hope it could help you to understand and use it next time yourself. Bests

Answer (score 3):

something like that can do the trick in bash for all files in current directory

```
for filename in *;do
    mv "$filename" "${filename:0:4}0${filename:5:11}"
done
```